# Dovecot 1:2.3.7.2-1ubuntu3.3 not logging failed authentication on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS server

Tags: 20.04, authentication, log, mail-server, dovecot

I am running Dovecot 1:2.3.7.2-1ubuntu3.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS server. My postfix/dovecot self hosted mail server works fine! I can send and receive mail without any problem. All the packages relating to mail server setup and the OS itself is update to date at the time of writing this question.
What I am trying to do is to block spam logins with the help of fail2ban which relies on dovecot logs. Fail2ban setup is not working because dovecot does not log anything relating to authentication. Although I see other kind of logs.

Output of `sudo dovecot -n`:

```
# 2.3.7.2 (3c910f64b): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.5.7.2 ()
# OS: Linux 5.4.0-58-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 
# Hostname: **redacted**
auth_debug = yes
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = sha1
dict {
  quota = pgsql:/etc/dovecot/dovecot-dict-sql.conf.ext
}
info_log_path = /var/log/dovecot-info.log
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_home = /var/vmail/%d/%n/
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_plugins = quota
mail_privileged_group = mail
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Archive {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Archive
  }
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Flagged {
    auto = subscribe
    comment = All my flagged messages
    special_use = \Flagged
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
plugin {
  quota = dict:User quota::proxy::quota
  quota_grace = 10%%
  quota_max_mail_size = 26M
  quota_rule = *:storage=4096M
  quota_rule2 = Trash:storage=+200M
  quota_warning = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
  quota_warning2 = storage=80%% quota-warning 80 %u
  quota_warning4 = -storage=100%% quota-warning -100 %u
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
  sieve_before = /var/mail/SpamToJunk.sieve
}
protocols = imap pop3 lmtp sieve imap lmtp sieve pop3
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
service dict {
  unix_listener dict {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0660
    user = vmail
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
service quota-warning {
  executable = script /usr/local/bin/quota-warning.sh
  unix_listener quota-warning {
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
ssl_cert = **redacted**
ssl_dh = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_key = # hidden, use -P to show it
ssl_min_protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers = yes
userdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
verbose_ssl = yes
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
}
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = quota imap_quota
}
```

Output of `sudo doveadm log find`:

```
Debug: /var/log/dovecot-info.log
Info: /var/log/dovecot-info.log
Warning: /var/log/dovecot.log
Error: /var/log/dovecot.log
Fatal: /var/log/dovecot.log
```

Status report from systemctl shows that dovecot is running and no other info.

I tried many configs relating to logs but with no luck (and of course, restarting dovecot after config change). Please let me know if I need to provided more info. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20. There is 20.10 and 20.04. Which is it.

Comment: @David pardon. it is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the issue got fixed for me. Although I could not find any cause of the issue. (not an answer)